# python niftynet illegal instruction core dumped

Tags: python-3.x, niftynet

I am trying the Quickstart commands on niftynet's website.
As I run 
    net_download dense_vnet_abdominal_ct_model_zoo 
I get Illegal instruction (core dumped). 
Does someone have a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you are referring to https://niftynet.io/? Could you provide the commands you used?

Answer (score 0):

check your permission as miniconda is an installation in the root or other users.